# Multiple arguments (with struct) error using pthread

Tags: c++, struct, pthreads, arguments

I'm working on a multiclient chat project.

Here is my code:

```
struct RecvDataModel
{
    int sockAddr;
    char *inData;
};

void *ProcessData(void *arg);

void Client::Recv(int sockAddr, char *inData)
{
    RecvDataModel outData;
    outData.sockAddr = sockAddr;
    outData.inData = inData;
    pthread_t rThr;
    pthread_create(&rThr, NULL, ProcessData, (void*)&outData);
}

void *ProcessData(void *arg)
{
    RecvDataModel *inData = (RecvDataModel*)arg;
    cout << inData->inData << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Basically if sockAddr (in Client::Recv) equals "55" ProcessData's cout function writing "31784736", if equals "0" cout's "5120"

That's my big problem! I can't continue without this! (I'm using eclipse C++)
What's the problem? I have already looked some example projects like this: [Link >>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352749/multiple-arguments-to-function-called-by-pthread-create)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing a pointer to a `RecvDataModel` which is a function-local variable. It will go out of scope at the end of the `Client::Recv` function.

Try allocating it with `new` instead:

```
RecvDataModel * outData = new RecvDataModel();
outData->sockAddr = sockAddr;
outData->inData = inData;
pthread_t rThr;
pthread_create(&rThr, NULL, ProcessData, outData);
```

Comment: now it cout's "32041692" for sockAddr "0"
Edit: sorry about this, it works! (not worked in the first because i have used "pthread_create(&rThr, NULL, ProcessData, &outData);" instead of "pthread_create(&rThr, NULL, ProcessData, outData);" thank you very much! :)

Comment: @freaka61 You may want to delete `inData` when you're done with it in `ProcessData()` to avoid leaking memory.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson how? like close()?

Comment: hmm, can i delete it in ProcessData()?

Comment: like that?
  void Client::Recv(int sockAddr, char *inData)
{
...
delete outData;
}
 and 
void *ProcessData(void *arg)
{
...
delete inData;
}

Comment: @freaka61 Yes, you've allocated it with `new` and passed it to `ProcessData`. Once you're done with it in `ProcessData`, you'll need to do `delete inData;` or it will never be released.

Comment: @freaka61 Just noticed from your example above that you're asking if you should delete it twice, no you should not delete outData in Recv, you'll still want it to be allocated when you get to ProcessData.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson if i delete in only ProcessData() will it be deleted(no memory usage)?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Err... there is an other problem. sockAddr works fine with struct but i can't take *inData?

Answer (score 2):

Don't pass around pointers to local variables that go out of scope.  As soon as you create that thread, `outData` isn't valid anymore, and so the pointer you gave to it is no good.  You need to declare `outData` with a `static` qualifier, or allocate space for it dynamically so that it doesn't vanish when `Client::Recv` returns.